# SSRS 2017 ReportViewer.WebForms localization

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, localization

I am using SSRS 2017 ReportViewer.WebForms in my app, and I want to localize it. I made

```
public class ReportViewerCustomMessages : IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages
{
    ...
}
```

and it works. But I can't localize export types, they are very strange

[image]

Is it possible to localize (or change texts) export types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's easy...

```
public string GetLocalizedNameForRenderingExtension(string format)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case "XML":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportXML;
                case "CSV":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportCSV;
                case "PDF":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportPDF;
                case "MHTML":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportMHTML;
                case "EXCELOPENXML":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportEXCELOPENXML;
                case "IMAGE":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportIMAGE;
                case "WORDOPENXML":
                    return Messages.RV_ExportWORDOPENXML;
            }

            return format;
        }
```